# Check for browser optional chaining support in Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In an Angular app, I want to check client's browser native support to optional chaining (es2020) in order to load a library which have a modern ES version and a legacy one.

The problem is: Angular compiler (I believe it's actually tsc genera behaviour) transpiles everything to targeted ES version (es6 in my case), breaking the code I would use to check for optional chaining support (breaking in the sense that it won't work to check optional chaining support during runtime):

```html
export function isOpChainingSupported(): boolean {
  const opChainingChecker = {
    support: true
  };
  try {
    // CODE BEFORE TRANSPILING:
    // return opChainingChecker?.support;
    //
    // TURNS INTO
    return
      opChainingChecker === null || opChainingChecker === void 0 ? 
      void 0 :
      opChainingChecker.support;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I tried using moving this code to a function in a plain JS file, using the 'allowJs' TS config in order to import it without errors...no go: tsc ends up transpiling it too.

Now I can see three options I don't really like:

- Using eval('constObj?.prop'), which is not a good option according to most sources I've checked for security reasons;
- Using my plain JS file as an asset, loading it dynamically;
- Creating a ES utility library for this function (my choice right now, even though I see it as an overkill for my problem).

What I wanted to ask is: is there something I'm not seeing? A simpler solution that I've missed?

Sorry in advance if this is a bad question, but I feel like when we "tinker" too much with a problem, it's always better to ask people with a fresh view of the picture!

Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, @Keith. My description wasn't really clear...from 'breaking' I mean: the code won't work to check for optional chaining, since the line which would check it gets converted to a regular 'obj !== undefined && obj.prop'. I'll edit my question to clear this point...sorry again!

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you need to know?.  TSC will convert optional chaining based on the target, so nothing should change.  `eval` should be fine if you really need to check, if you don't want to use eval, another idea place this check code in another directory, and place a `tsconfig.json` and set the target to say `ES2020`,  ps.  I don't use angular, but I'm assuming it respects `tsconfig.json`..

Comment: That's true for all artifacts included in tsconfig.json, but there are a few cases where that doesn't hold: I'm using PDF.js, which have two distributions: a modern version, which uses some of the latest ES features, and a Legacy version which uses regular ES5. The idea is: depending on the browser support I would load the modern version, which gives the best performance. As the minified JS is loaded dinamically (as an asset), TSC won't touch it.

Comment: That makes sense, in that case I would just go the `eval` route.  I know they say `eval` is `evil`, but it's sometimes it's just the right thing to do.  Here seems a really good reason to use `eval`..  You could maybe use `new Function` too, but to be fair it's pretty much the same thing..  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: aren't you compiling your code down when using angular? I mean what would you do with result of the check?

Comment: Hey @TheFool ! So, Angular code is compiled, but there are plain JS libraries which can use all kinds of ES newer features. In my particular case, it's the library PDF.js. It has two releases: the normal one, which uses all these features, and the legacy one, which is compatible with ES5. Obviously, if a user's browser is compatible with ES latest features, loading PDF.js normal release would be better, since it results in a better experience performancewise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've already went with one of the options described in the question, I thought it would be good to answer it.

In my first attempt, I've tried the "third party library" solution, but it didn't work: when there's a syntax error (which is the case if we use optional chaining in a browser without support), the exception happens before the browser actually runs that code, leading to two results:

- The exception won't be caught in a try/catch block;
- The current "execution context" will end abruptly.

So, I needed a way to run the "checker code" in a separate context, in order to keep my main thread (and consequently, my app) from dying. Also, I needed a way to check if the code ran successfully or not.

The final solution I've come up with is a mix between two of the options: I've created a library which loads a simple script testing for optional chaining support, returning a Promise with a boolean indicating the browser's support.

The script is loaded dinamically, by adding a temporary script tag (which isolates the execution from the main context, preventing the SyntaxError from killing the app). In order to improve security, I've used the integrity attribute.

If anyone is going through the same issue, you can use my solution by installing the npm library [optional-chaining-checker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/optional-chaining-checker) and following the instructions. I've tried to make it as customizable as I could, but if it doesn't attend your needs, feel free to check out my [repository](https://github.com/LAlves91/optional-chaining-checker) and adapt the code at will!